# Taizé prayer in Lisbon: where?

Tags: religion, portugal, lisbon

I'm going to Lisbon for 5 days. Where I live use to go to the Taize' prayer in some Parrish. I know this is international and that many people, after coming back to Taizé, start to pray the same way in small group within the local church.

Does any of you know if there are any regular Taizé prayers in Lisbon and if it would be possible to get in contact with them and to join the prayer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Paróquia de São Nicolau (Church of St. Nicholas) [official website](http://www.paroquiasaonicolau.pt/taize/):

> Uma proposta de experiência orante em sintonia com o ritmo da comunidade de Taizé, todas as 6ª feiras das 20h às 21h.

Roughly translated as:

> Come for a prayerful experience in tune with the pace of the Taizé
>   Community, **every Friday from 20:00 to 21:00.**

[Reviews of the church](https://foursquare.com/v/igreja-paroquial-de-s%C3%A3o-nicolau/4d39f47e0333a09383d64f34) on Foursquare confirm it as well:

> Taizé Prayer: Every Friday at 19h45m. Come and join us!